# Looking for replacement surface mount component in MacBook Air (A1466) mainboard

Tags: macbook-pro, motherboard

After liquid damage my backlight was broken. So I had to change the D68B chip.

After the replacement I lost a device. Please see below link for the photo of the diode/resistor/whatever I'm looking for on the motherboard.

[image]

It is a motherboard of a Macbook Air A1466 EMC 2925 Early 2015.

I need to replace it but I don't know the specs. Is there a diagram sheet?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you think it's a diode at not a resistor? It's just asking for the resistance of a diode doesn't make much sense, and if it is a diode you can see from the datasheet for what seems to be an equivalent part the recommendations for a diode: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp8550.pdf

Comment: Thanks @PeterJ and PC Techneer. I’ve edited this so it’s less certain a diode is needed.

Answer (score 2):

That looks more like a capacitor than a diode. Anyway, here's a link to download the schematic and boardview for it:
https://github.com/pctechneer/Diagnostic/blob/master/820-000165.zip
Use Open Board Viewer (at  https://openboardview.org/) to view the .brd file.
See https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macbook-air-a1466-no-power-wont-start.2179208/ for the board project I've been playing with.

Comment: Okay, I looked it up for you. It's R7753, 5%, 0, 0201, 1/20W on Open Board Viewer. So, a resistor. If it's difficult to tell what's bad. It's even more difficult to find replacement parts.